# Migrar un proyecto desarrollado en VisualStudio+Windows a VisualStudio+Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, macos, automapper

tengo un problema, tengo un proyecto desarrollado en visual studio 2019, con entity framework , web api, automapper, entre otras cosas, esto realizado para el framework de windows, el 4.5...Ahora quiero migrar este desarrollo y abrirlo en VisualStudio para Mac(Catalina) y seguir desarrollando en Mac, es posible esto? alguien hizo algo parecido? Cuales son los pasos a seguir? gracias.

Comment: El objetivo sería hacer que el código funcione con .Net Core. Yo hice una migración de un proyecto similar, hice un proyecto nuevo de .Net Core y empecé a mover controladores y vistas y ajustar el código que no funcionaba. Es importante primero estudiar un poco de .Net Core para entenderlo y adaptarlo.

Comment: uh que trabajo, es la unica forma? o es la que pudiste hacer vos?
y para que ese proyecto, una vez pasada a .Net Core, corra en el servidor que antes corria .Net(windows), hay que instalar algo? o hacer algo? gracias

Comment: No sé si sea la única pero fue la que me pareció más segura y eficiente porque casi fue solo copiar  y pegar  código, me parece que hay una guía de migración en el sitio de microsoft que hace algo parecido. El servidor debe tener soporte para .Net Core para que la aplicación funcione ahí, no he configurado servidores, el hosting donde estaba la aplicación ya tenía soporte así que solo tuve que desplegarla y estaba funcionando. **Importante** hay que revisar que todas las bibliotecas de terceros que usa el proyecto sean compatibles con .Net Core antes de iniciar la migración.

Comment: Claro Lobos, yo uso automapper por ejemplo, tengo que ver si es compatible, entity framework lo deberia cargar bien, quiza cambie algun parametro, nombre de algun metodo supongo.Y me pasa lo mismo que vos, he tocado el servidor pero no se donde se configura para que soporte el framework de .net core...